# difference in default delimiter and field calculation in cut and awk

Tags: awk, field, cut

I am trying to cut out the time that a process starts. 
This is the ps line. Is seems delimited by spaces.

```
 casper@casperhost02 1065$ ps -ef | grep [t]xg casper  5345     1 34 16:40 ?        00:06:56 q /casper_apps/casper/reader/q/txg_dr.q -g 1 -w 80000 -p 3041 -taq /casper_apps/casper/data/fiofs/hdb0 -bin /casper_apps/casper/reader/q -t1 /casper_apps/casper/data/file -cmq /casper_apps/casper/common/q -ref /casper_apps/casper/static -prg txg_dr
```

I wanted to just cut the time from the ps line and extract by field.. 
when I use cut and delimit by space, the time is in field ten.

```
casper@casperhost02 1075$ ps -ef | grep [t]xg | cut -d' ' -f10
```

16:40

However when I use awk, which id default delimited by space, it is field 5.

```
 casper@casperhost02 1076$ ps -ef | grep [t]xg | awk '{print $5}'
```

16:40

What is the difference between the field delimiter in awk and cut?

Comment: `awk` "squeezes" all contiguous white space by default to a single delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut` accepts a single-character delimiter, and is suitable only for very simple text file formats.

Awk is much more versatile, and can handle somewhat more complex field delimiter definitions and even (in some dialects) a regular expression.  By default, Awk regards *sequences of* whitespace as a single delimiter.

Tangentially, you seem to be looking for the command `pgrep`.  If you have to reinvent it, keep in mind that `grep x | awk '{y}'` can almost always be written `awk '/x/{y}'`.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` counts the spaces, `awk` counts the fields, treating all the contiguous white space as one delimiter by default.  Note that you don't need `grep` if you are already using `awk`

```
 ... |  awk '/txg/{print $5}'
```

you can also restrict the regex (or literal) match to the right field and eliminate false positives.